# Elasticsearch Java API from 2.x to 5.x issues

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've updated to elasticsearch java library version 5.2.0.

In 2.x,

1. I was using `SearchRequestBuilder.addField()` in order to add a field to the search request. Nevertheless, It seems to be replaced. I've written the available methods intellisense is showing me. Which of them do I need to pick?

   - `addDocValueField`
   - `addFieldDataField`
   - `addScriptField`
   - `addStoredField`
   - `storedFields`
   - `fields`
2. `SearchRequestBuilder.setNoFields` is also removed. Which would be the alternative?
3. Currently, I'm calling scripts from Java using this code. Is there any more elegant way to call it in 5.x Java API?

Code:

```
return AggregationBuilders
    .terms(this.getName())
    .field(this.getName())
    .script(new Script(
        ScriptType.FILE,
        "painless",
        "year",
        ImmutableMap.of("field", this.getName())
    )
);
```

As you can see I setting `field` as script parameter. Nevertheless, I don't quite understand how to get it from script code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, [go to the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/ce625ebdccc35639d7423ad6309119422c99ccf3/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.java#L253-L283)

1. use `setFetchSource(String[] includes, String[] excludes)` instead
2. use `setFetchSource(false)` instead
3. if you need to execute this script for each document, you can use `addScriptField()`

Comment: I'm trying to call a script. It compiles and runs correctly, nevertheless, I think it's a no _elegant_ way in contrast with the all api... Is there another way to call a script?

Comment: The question is what does your script and in which context do you need to run it?

Comment: Do I need to set a exclude value for each source field I want to include? It's a bit noising, isn't it?

Comment: The script goal is to get the year part of a date field.

Comment: What fields do you need to include?

Comment: you can execute your script in a script field then, so it executes for each document, using `addScriptField()`

Comment: Some comments before I comment that using `addScriptField` is a bit noising solution since I need to set which fields I want to fetch and which ones I want to exclude. So, each time I want to add a field to fetch I need to set I don't exclude any field. Isn't there any slight method in order to add a field to fetch? I don't if I've explained so well.

Comment: Example: `for (String field : fields) this.provideSearchRequest().setFetchSource(field, null);` I'm using an incremental way (this is an approach (I'm not using a `loop`) to add fields to fetch...

Comment: `setFetchSource` can take array of fields for both includes and excludes

Comment: `addScriptField` is only useful for adding a specific script field computed out of other document fields

Comment: My question is: `setFetchSource` is incremental? or remove previously `includes` and `excludes` information?

Comment: `setFetchSource` is not incremental, but `addScriptField` is. You can incrementally build an array of fields that you can then feed to `setFetchSource` though